# Folder name with Parentheses in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, directory

So,
I have parentheses in folder name with spaces:

folder\folder (2000)\file.srt

folder\folder (1990)\file.srt

```
for file in `find . -name "*.srt"`
do
 echo "file = $file";
done
```

Don't work in my script. Anyone can help-me?

Comment: Don't work for me.
[Look Here](https://gist.github.com/oe1tkt/e9182b32382f78a41c1a) I'm using this script, but in my structure don't work, because this () in folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find -exec` for this:

```
find . -name "*.srt" -exec echo "file = {}" \;
```

Output:

```
file = ./folder/folder (1990)/file.srt
file = ./folder/folder (2000)/file.srt
```

Comment: Don't work here, need it in loop. I used echo just as an example. My script uses the iconv. Thanks for now.

Comment: [Look Here](https://gist.github.com/oe1tkt/e9182b32382f78a41c1a) I'm using this script, but in my structure don't work, because this () in folder name.

Comment: @LetterLin I think the problem is actually the spaces. Try this:
`files=$(find . -name '*.srt')`
`while read f; do echo "file: $f"; done <<< $files`

Comment: [FONT](https://gist.github.com/letterlin1/9556d743667d2c8d7c95cceab724b5a7) Not yet. Look in font. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the spaces in the filenames produced by `find(1)` are getting interspersed into the names separated by `\n`s, and the `for` command gets them all without differencing them.

The best approach (and one that saves commands) is to use `find(1)` with the `-print0` option, that prints the filenames separated by a null character, and then use the `xargs` command with the `-0` option, which expects nulls as separators.  This way you can execute a command with as much parameters as the system can afford.  For example

```
find . -type f -name "* *" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

will print the contents of all files that have a space in their name.

In your example, you want to do some scripting with each data line, so a better approach will be to use the `read` shell command, as in (in this case, you don't need the `-print0` option, as the files are delimited by newlines, so you'll read a file per read)

```
find . -name "*.srt" | while read file
do
    echo "file = ${file}"
done
```

but in this case you'll not get the efficient `xargs(1)` use, putting as many parameters in the command line of the called command as possible.  You'll process each file one file at a time.